# Who is the "I" in "I Dream of Jeannie"?

Tags: title, i-dream-of-jeannie

Used to watch this show as a kid in the 1980s, when I stayed home from school (it was broadcast each weekday on a second-tier network, like a lot of sitcoms from earlier decades).

Thinking about it recently, and wondering specifically about the title -- **to whom does the "I" in "I Dream of Jeannie" refer?**

### [image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The "I" does not refer to any specific in-show character.  The show takes its name from the opening line of the Stephen Foster song [Jeanie with the Light Brown Hair](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeanie_with_the_Light_Brown_Hair), from 1854:

> The opening line notably got used as the basis for the title of the TV
>   series I Dream of Jeannie.

Here it is on [Youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sKdq249uOGs).

The opening line is "I dream of Jeanie with the light brown hair."

Comment: I think that adding the lyrics to your answer will be a  nice bonus :) +1

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I edited by adding the opening line from the song. The "light brown hair" part might also explain why the show's creator originally tried to avoid casting a blonde.

Comment: @ShaneFinneran I believe that Sidney Sheldon wanted a brunette in order to avoid his genie looking like the one on _Bewitched_ which was a show on a rival network.

Comment: @coleopterist - There is no way those two would ever be mistaken for one another. One could act, the other had large breasts.